# NSRunningApplication.h: "Not all applications have a pid"

Tags: cocoa, unix, pid

From the comment on `processIdentifier` in `NSRunningApplication.h`:

> Not all applications have a pid.

Huh?

I can see this happening in the specific case of an `NSRunningApplication` representing a terminated process (`runningProcess.terminated == YES`), but I can't think of an example of an running application NOT having a process ID. That's kinda Unix 101.

Documentation bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, from the documentation: “Do not rely on this for comparing processes, instead compare NSRunningApplication instances using `isEqual:`.”

Answer (score 8):

It's a hedge.  A "running application" is something that the user thinks of as an application.  Shows up in the cmd-tab switcher, etc.  That need not necessarily correspond directly to a process.  In the classic environment, multiple applications were hosted by a single unix process, classic.  In this situation NSRunningApplication would return -1 for each "application".

People who had been at it long enough had seen enough interesting hacks that they thought this was an important thing to define.

Comment: I've never heard the term "hedge" used for something like this before (but I think I can grok the meaning from the context). Could you explain that, please?

Comment: I think it comes from the idiom "hedging your bets". It just means they're trying to cover all their bases (Which is yet another idiom--yay English!).

Comment: The running applications list isn't all GUI apps. Some faceless apps (LSUIElement=1) show up too: the AppleSpell service, loginwindow, and user-run daemons among others.